# Extract parameter from JSON that starts with @ special character

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How could I extract `id` from the API response in React when the `id` is available with `@` character?

Simply using `response.id` or `response.channelId` is not working.

```
{
    @categoryId: "3605",
    @channelId: "0",
    @id: "12012"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i simply tried accessing id by response.id but  is not working. the other parameter that start without @ in the beginning  works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is worth trying to access object field by array-like operator:

```
const object = {
    "@categoryId": "3605",
    "@channelId": "0",
    "@id": "12012",
}
```

Property access:

```
  { object["@categoryId"] }
  { object["@channelId"] }
  { object["@id"] }
```

[image: Edit 7jpqjww3rj]

Comment: yes you are correct. i manage to extract the id by : object["@id"]